# How to export and import modules in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-typescript

I have a React Typescript project and use Craco. I have a CommonJS repo bundle which I want to integrate into the project.

Using Craco start, the project works and there are no problems. On the build however, the error is:

Attempted import error: 'B' is not exported from './test' (imported as 'test').

I tried simplifying the problem by using a test and basically this is what we have.

File: ./test.js

```
class A {

    test() {
        console.log('a')
    }
}

module.exports = A


class B {

    test() {
        console.log('a')
    }
}

module.exports = B

module.exports = {
    A,
    B
}
```

File: ./service.ts

```
import * as test from './test'
console.log(test.B)
```

I think it is something with the Webpack on Craco build and other types of JS maybe?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes it works but this is an example, I just posted my actual issue which I have not solved yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74667594/craco-build-a-browserified-module-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wrong export you need to change your code like this**

Page 1)

```
 export class A {
        
            test() {
                console.log('a')
            }
        }
        
        
        
    export  class B {
        
            test() {
                console.log('a')
            }
        }
```

Page 2

```
    import * as test from './test'
console.log(new test.B().test())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export the classes this way

```
    class A {
      test() {
        console.log("A");
      }
    }
    
    
    class B {
      test() {
        console.log("B");
      }
    }
    
    export default {
      A,
      B
    };
```

And import it:

```
import test from "./test";
const bbb = new test.B();
```

You can read more about how to export/import modules [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-import-and-export-a-module-in-typescript)